# PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I have titanic dataset downloaded from kaggle.
I am implementing pandas's profiling by installing pandas_profiling

your contribution will be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('E:/pythonWorkspace/excelFiles/train.csv')
df.head()

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
prof = ProfileReport(df) #object created!
prof.to_file(output_file='output.html')
```

Error :

```
PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/u/import-error
```

Comment: `pandas_profiling` is now outdated, and has changed its name to `ydata_profiling`.  You should switch.

Answer (score 9):

First you need to install [ydata-profiling](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling):

```
pip install ydata-profiling
```

Then:

```
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

# Read the data from a csv file 
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Generate the data profiling report 
report = ProfileReport(df, title='My Data')
report.to_file("my_report.html")
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this issue is due to pydantic v2 having breaking changes compared to from v1.

#### Solution

Revert to Pydantic v1 by running

```bash
pip install "pydantic==1.*"
```

#### Alternative Solution

Change the failing part of the code to use the new import structure found in Pydantic v2

```py
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, I was importing BaseSettings with: from pydantic import BaseSettings & was getting this error. I believe the answer Elijas mentioned will work, the conflict between v2 & v1 but I also found this to work with v2: from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by @SeaEngineering, but I got environment conflicts that kept returning erros.

I fixed it by just installing ydata-profiling using condas:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge ydata-profiling
```

This will install ydata-profiling and fix any environment conflicts you might have.

After installing just replace

```py
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

with

```py
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```