# when importing pandas_profiling error `pydantic-settings`

Tags: pandas, pandas-profiling, python-3.12

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport error pydantic-settings

raise PydanticImportError(f'`{import_path}` has been removed in V2.')

PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

i try everything but nothing work

!pip install -U pandas-profiling

import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Be sure to read up on [the question asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to get better responses faster. I believe your question [is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76667611/). `pandas_profiling` is outdated, the library `ydata_profiling` should be able to get the functionality you're after.

Answer (score 0):

the name of this package has been changed. u need to reinstall "pip install ydata-profiling", and "from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).